# Make content scrollable in css table layout

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have the following layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
<body> 
    <div class="lbme-wrapper">
    <div class="header-1 lbme-row">
        <div class="col-left">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-middle">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-2 lbme-row">
        <div class="col-left">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-middle">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lbme-nav-container lbme-row">
        <div class="col-left">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-middle">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-lbme">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-row lbme-row">
        <div class="col-left ">
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-stacked-lbme">
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-middle">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right  hidden-xs">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="lbme-row">
        <div class="col-left ">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-middle">
            1 Besucher online
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
  </body>

</html>
```

And CSS-File:

```css
html,body{ margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%; }

.lbme-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
.content-row {
    height: 100%
}
.content-row .col-right, .content-row .col-middle,.content-row .col-left {
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.header-2 {
    height: 100px;
}
.lbme-nav-container {
    height: 94px !important;
}
.lbme-row{
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}
.lbme-row .col-right, .lbme-row .col-left, .lbme-row .col-middle  {
    display:table-cell;
    border:0;
}
.col-middle {
    background: gray;
}
.lbme-row .col-right, .lbme-row .col-left {
    width:160px;
    background: #eee;
}
.navbar-container .col-left {
    height: 94px;
}
.navbar-lbme {
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar-lbme .navbar-nav > li > a{
    width: 86px;
    height: 86px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 4px;
}
.nav-stacked-lbme > li > a {
    padding: 2px 0 2px 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.nav-stacked-lbme > li > a:hover {
    background: #aaa;
}
footer {
    background: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.content-row .col-middle {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And my question is, why can I not scroll in .content-row .col-middle?
I have tried all overflow values to .content-row .col-middle. Is that problem because of `table-layout: fixed;` or `poistion: fixed`?

https://jsfiddle.net/nnm1q02h/

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the `overflow: hidden` property from `lbme-wrapper` since this is the fixed positioned wrapper where your table is positioned. change it to `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` and it works.

```
.lbme-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px red solid;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

here is your working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/31szb689/